# Wordpress AJAX controller

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I want to make a PHP filed called ajax_controller that will handle all ajax requests. However when I visit that page I get redirected to a 404 (maybe because it's searching for a page).

How can i tell wordpress that ajax_controller is not a page and should not render the `enqueue_header(), enqueue_footer()` functions. I should be able to visit it through url/ajax_controller but it should be an empty page.

### ajax_controller.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_send_email', 'send_email_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email_callback');


function send_email()
{
//do something;

}
```

### jquery

```
var fruit = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_controller,
        data: {
            'action':'send_email',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: the code in your controller points to ajax.php anyway. You can set up a php file and allow access to it in htaccess if you dont like the wp way of doing it , but it seems kinda pointless when the current system handles it.

Comment: This is not how it's done, my friend.

Comment: @David where do I send the request to sending it to ajax_controller gives me a 404

Comment: use the js variable `ajaxurl` (it may have been defined for you already) or use `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?> ` to get the correct url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a folder in your plugins directory called `my-ajax-handler`.

Step 2: Create two files in that directory: `my-ajax-handler.php` and `my-ajax-handler.js`

Step 3: In `my-ajax-handler.php`, paste the following code:

```
<?php
/*
** Plugin Name: My Ajax Handler
** Description: A simple plugin to handle all my ajax.
** Version: 1
** Author: Me
*/

class MyAjaxHandler
{
    public static $file, $dir, $url;
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$file = __FILE__;
        self::$dir = dirname(self::$file);
        self::$url = plugins_url('', self::$file);
        add_action('init', array($this, 'register'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'js'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_handler', array($this, 'ajax'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_handler', array($this, 'ajax'));
    }
    public function register()
    {
        wp_register_script('my-ajax-handler', self::$url.'/my-ajax-handler.js', array('jquery'));   
    }
    public function js()
    {
        $vars = array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my-ajax-handler-nonce'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax-handler');
        wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handler', 'my_ajax_handler', $vars);    
    }
    public function ajax()
    {
        if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'my-ajax-handler-nonce')) die('Nonce failed.');    
        $response = 'An '.$_POST['fruit'].' a day keeps the doctor away';
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
}
new MyAjaxHandler;
```

Step 4: In `my-ajax-handler.js`, paste the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    var fruit = 'apple';
    $.post
    (
        my_ajax_handler.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'my_ajax_handler',
            fruit : fruit,
            nonce : my_ajax_handler.nonce
        },
        function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );  
});
```

Step 5: Save the documents and activate your plugin.